# How can one check to see if a remote file exists using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I check a File exits in a web location in ASP.Net(in a different web application, but same web server), currently I doing like this. Is there any better way of doing this?

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
            try
            {
                Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://localhost/images/myimage.jpg");
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    //exists
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //Not exists
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file is accessible via HTTP, you can issue a HTTP HEAD requrest for that particular URL using `HttpWebRequest`. If `HttpWebResponse.StatusCode` will be 200, than file is there.

**EDIT**: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366848/httpwebrequest-getresponse-throws-webexception-on-http-304) on why `GetResponse` throws stupid exceptions when it actually should not do that.

Comment: HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("url") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "HEAD";
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)

I wrote the code like this, but I am getting exception from GetResponse() line itself.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you are never going to get a 100% definitive response on the existence of a file, but the way I do it would be pretty similar to yours...

```
bool remoteFileExists(string addressOfFile)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(addressOfFile) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
        var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);  
    }
    catch(WebException wex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT :: looking at the edit by Anton Gogolev above ([How can one check to see if a remote file exists using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443359/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-c/1443367#1443367)) I should have cast the response to a HttpWebResponse object and checked the status code.  Edited the code to reflect that

Comment: I am getting a WebException from the GetResponse() line, if the file not exists. So I can't get the count of response headers.

Comment: @Anuraj - Yes, that is expected (although undesirable) behaviour. I'd rather not use exceptions for flow, but there's not a lot else I can suggest off the top of my head....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Server.MapPath to get the directory and then check if file exist using IO standard methods like File.Exists

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it, its on a different web application, so I can't use Server.MapPath.

Answer (score -1):

The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server but the server could not find what was requested. A 404 error indicates that the requested resource may be available in the future.

You can use a HEAD request (HttpWebRequest.Method = "HEAD")