# jquery getJSON function not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using $.getJSON to load a JSON file. The file appears to load successfully (I can see its contents in Firebug below a heading that reads "GET http://siteinfo/data/library.json 304 not modified"). However if I try to use console.log or alert inside the success function it doesn't work):

```
$.getJSON('data/library.json', function(data){
    alert('HERE');
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data.library, function(k,v){
        console.log(k + "/" + v);

    });
});
```

None of the alerts or console.logs are working. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Nothing :( All I see is "GET http://site/data/library.json
 
304 Not Modified
  189ms"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `304` status code. That's why response not coming in `success` function its going to `error` function because `error` is a function to be called if the request fails.

There is something wrong with server side. Read [Why am I getting "(304) Not Modified" error on some links when using HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603595/why-am-i-getting-304-not-modified-error-on-some-links-when-using-httpwebrequ) for more details.

Add this error handler in ajax request. You can handle error in ajax. This is following function equivalent to your `getJSON`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get", 
    url: "data/library.json",
    datatype: "json"
    success: function (data, text) {
        alert('HERE');
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.library, function(k,v){
            console.log(k + "/" + v);

        });
    },
   //add this error handler you'll get alert
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: This time I do get the alert with the Json contents. But why is it not succeeding?

Comment: Sorry, what does that mean, how can I change that?

Comment: Will check that link you sent me. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out the problem was an easy fix. I used the code you sent me to get the error and turns out Dreamweaver had added a comment on the first line of the JSON file.  As soon as I removed it, the success function was executed. Now it all works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with caching, you could try doing your request like this, turning caching off

```
 $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "get",
      url: 'data/library.json',
      cache:false,
      success: function(data){
        alert('HERE');
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.library, function(k,v){
        console.log(k + "/" + v);
        });
      }
    });
```