# What does 304 not modified means in console status means?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am studying node js with simple chat. Here's my sample code:

**server.js**

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    client = require('socket.io').listen(8888).sockets;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Node Chat System</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="chat">
            <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Enter your name" />
            <div class="chat-messages"></div>
            <textarea placeholder="Enter your message" ></textarea>
            <div class="chat-status">Status: <span>Idle</span></div>
            <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then I restart the node server
then I load my page and check the console > net tab

And then my status in accessing the socket.io is this:

```
304 Not Modified
```

And in my tutorial it should be

```
200 Ok
```

By the way I am using wampserver as well and when I stop all process still the same effect.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Did you change index.html?

Comment: What do you mean `did you change` ?

Comment: 304 just means that the server doesn't think your cached contents are out of date.  It's an attempt at optimization (rather than re-send the contents, it just says that "what you have in the cache is okay").  I'm wondering if there's actually a problem.

Comment: So 304 is actually not an error?

Comment: Likely not, unless there's a weird caching issue.  Though, I was likely wrong about index.html; that probably doesn't matter, but rather the socket.io JS is what the 304 is about.  Regardless, one easy thing to test is see what happens if you clear your cache; does that result in 200?

Comment: Still the same status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91994/discussion-between-ironcache-and-jerielle).

Answer (score 8):

In your specific case, the node.js server is just telling the browser that it's cached version of `socket.io.js` is not out of date, so just use the one it already has in the cache.  This is normal expected browser behavior for cacheable files.  If you clear your browser cache, the restart the browser, then repeat this test, the first time you load the file, you should see a 200 status (since the cache was empty, the browser will not issue a conditional GET request).  After that, once the file is cached, you should get 304 again.

---

A description of the 304 return status is right here in the spec (and also the very first result in a Google search):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5

> 10.3.5 304 Not Modified
>
> If the client has performed a conditional GET request and access is
>   allowed, but the document has not been modified, the server SHOULD
>   respond with this status code. The 304 response MUST NOT contain a
>   message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line
>   after the header fields.
>
> The response MUST include the following header fields:
>
> ```
>   - Date, unless its omission is required by section 14.18.1
> ```
>
> If a clockless origin server obeys these rules, and proxies and clients add their own Date to any response received without one (as already
>   specified by [RFC 2068], section 14.19), caches will operate
>   correctly.
>
> ```
>   - ETag and/or Content-Location, if the header would have been sent
>     in a 200 response to the same request
>   - Expires, Cache-Control, and/or Vary, if the field-value might
>     differ from that sent in any previous response for the same
>     variant
> ```
>
> If the conditional GET used a strong cache validator (see section 13.3.3), the response SHOULD NOT include other
>   entity-headers. Otherwise (i.e., the conditional GET used a weak
>   validator), the response MUST NOT include other entity-headers; this
>   prevents inconsistencies between cached entity-bodies and updated
>   headers.
>
> If a 304 response indicates an entity not currently cached, then the
>   cache MUST disregard the response and repeat the request without the
>   conditional.
>
> If a cache uses a received 304 response to update a cache entry, the
>   cache MUST update the entry to reflect any new field values given in
>   the response.

So, in a nutshell it means that if the client did a conditional GET request, then the server can return 304 which means that the content has not been modified since it was last requested and this a way for the server to communicate that back to the client without sending the content back again.  Basically, the client says "I'd like to know if you have a newer version of this content and here's the meta data on the version I already have.  If you don't have a newer version than what I already have, then just return a 304, otherwise send me the newer version".

And, if you want more explanation on a "conditional GET request", you can read about that here: https://ruturajv.wordpress.com/2005/12/27/conditional-get-request/

---

**More detail**

If you clear your browser cache and then fetch `socket.io.js`, you will see a 200 response status and a response header like this:

```
 ETag: xxxxx
```

Then, the next time your browser requests that same file, it will send a conditional GET request with this header in the request:

```
If-None-Match: xxxxx
```

Where `xxxxx` is the same string in both.

This is the browser telling the server that it already has a version of this file with a given ETag.  The server then checks to see if it's version of the file is that ETag or not.  If the ETag matches, then it returns 304.  In this case, the ETag is used as a version number.  In some cases, it is a hash of the file, but in the specific case of socket.io.js, it's actually a version number (since the server code knows intimately about that particular file).

Comment: @Jerielle - did this answer your question and explain how things work with 304?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I did what jfriend00 suggested, but it did not help.

And I found the following - it is not intended for Jerielle - I hope it will help someone.

To avoid this issue just open the following link (it is optional - see last paragraph below):

http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js

(please change 3000 to what you are using).

This will cache socket.io.js

After that open the page you need to open and first time you should get 200. Do not refresh page again - this way socket.io works as expected - communicates with server as it should ( in my case at least ).

If you hit refresh it returns 304 again - it may have something to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29464774) - something in this process, I guess, uses 'If-Modified-Since' and hence refresh returns 304 'Not modified'.

This means that in most cases socket.io should be able to successfully communicate with server even if you get 304 (even if you do not click on link above to cache socket.io.js).