# I keep getting this in my azure site log tail command

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Does it mean, my server is restarting every 4 mins, the site has 0 traffic currently except me pinging it whenever I load it, I am not loading it currently. I am new to the azure ecosystem. can someone please suggest what this would mean?

```
    info:    Executing command site log tail
2016-10-18T07:32:16  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2016-10-18 07:31:54 ~1ZUPBOT GET / - 80 - 100.76.188.54 AlwaysOn - - zupbot.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 2997 439 18
2016-10-18 07:31:54 ZUPBOT GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=c8c46896-3af9-47a0-b2f9-35fb1edb76ed 80 - 191.233.85.165 AlwaysOn ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 - zupbot.azurewebsites.net 301 0 0 622 616 15
2016-10-18T07:34:16  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2016-10-18T07:35:16  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2016-10-18T07:36:16  No new trace in the past 3 min(s).
2016-10-18T07:37:16  No new trace in the past 4 min(s).
2016-10-18 07:36:54 ~1ZUPBOT GET / - 80 - 100.76.188.54 AlwaysOn - - zupbot.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 2997 439 15
2016-10-18 07:36:54 ZUPBOT GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=c7e2f7bd-b7aa-434e-86f6-c91c75a9273a 80 - 191.233.85.165 AlwaysOn ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 - zupbot.azurewebsites.net 301 0 0 622 616 0
2016-10-18T07:39:16  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2016-10-18T07:40:16  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2016-10-18T07:41:16  No new trace in the past 3 min(s).
2016-10-18T07:42:16  No new trace in the past 4 min(s).
2016-10-18 07:41:55 ~1ZUPBOT GET / - 80 - 100.76.188.54 AlwaysOn - - zupbot.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 2997 439 16
2016-10-18 07:41:55 ZUPBOT GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=9ba777e9-75f6-4822-abfd-2a4414030caa 80 - 191.233.85.165 AlwaysOn ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 - zupbot.azurewebsites.net 301 0 0 622 616 10
2016-10-18T07:44:16  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2016-10-18T07:45:16  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2016-10-18 07:45:13 ~1ZUPBOT GET /DebugConsole X-ARR-LOG-ID=831b7b2a-36b2-4285-bf4a-44bfa1634f25 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 - zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 5456 1186 0
2016-10-18 07:45:13 ~1ZUPBOT GET /Content/Styles/FileBrowser.css X-ARR-LOG-ID=1fae3ae4-2c00-4fde-9684-a352a891e7a5 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 2283 1196 0
2016-10-18 07:45:13 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/filesystemhub/hubs X-ARR-LOG-ID=7506db2a-3209-4807-b847-5a427605188e 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 3982 1165 0
2016-10-18 07:45:13 ~1ZUPBOT GET /content/scripts/HelperScript.js X-ARR-LOG-ID=3eded296-cab8-41ac-9209-6c6af44e16c8 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 928 1183 31
2016-10-18 07:45:13 ~1ZUPBOT GET /Content/Images/Kudu.svg X-ARR-LOG-ID=68ee739a-c35d-4647-864a-84395a9d1c1f 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 4146 1192 15
2016-10-18 07:45:14 ~1ZUPBOT GET /Content/Images/paKman.gif X-ARR-LOG-ID=f9417b0f-39ec-4de7-a2fa-b9c2819fc401 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 8900 1196 0
2016-10-18 07:45:14 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/filesystemhub/negotiate clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22filesystemhub%22%7D%5D&_=1476776712064&X-ARR-LOG-ID=0945b13d-6f21-46e3-8912-e61e9beeef9e 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 927 1466 15
2016-10-18 07:45:14 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/commandstream/negotiate clientProtocol=1.4&shell=CMD&_=1476776712065&X-ARR-LOG-ID=50c75369-f3e8-44b7-b795-37a6c3bd4c87 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 927 1366 0
2016-10-18 07:45:14 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/filesystemhub/start transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=GCS79RrlnHMnFmIPrMvLpheeo4m1Gd%2FudwM7ob%2FTegTtyL21OW0hnz0yBGV94sTHK9iwgN%2BQOCxxgcwAIc5LzPNg1qeS65bjIVFw43t5WiGGmS2bTxVViA2yshyEpkoT&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22filesystemhub%22%7D%5D&_=1476776712066&X-ARR-LOG-ID=49fc358a-5e95-4fa6-922e-fa0679a2adf9 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 575 1814 0
2016-10-18 07:45:14 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/commandstream/start transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&shell=CMD&connectionToken=G%2BH2XNxiB1nlUwedD%2FJVPlw0aEpOXmen5n38IrNMt6rxwapqhtEp1%2BoMqTzbXK3GNlGhPhqzf7cWdO5XQbi%2BNN1UIAkq4g8X0q7x9FG%2B2wo9fMlSQxlONoiqaw45sKQM&_=1476776712067&X-ARR-LOG-ID=55d3d686-1eaf-47f6-85a7-36d2c1194c6a 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 575 1722 46
2016-10-18 07:45:14 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/vfs/ X-ARR-LOG-ID=468f231c-8f6b-44ed-93ae-5b27e900c2ad 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 1216 1171 15
2016-10-18 07:45:14 ~1ZUPBOT POST /api/filesystemhub/send transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=GCS79RrlnHMnFmIPrMvLpheeo4m1Gd%2FudwM7ob%2FTegTtyL21OW0hnz0yBGV94sTHK9iwgN%2BQOCxxgcwAIc5LzPNg1qeS65bjIVFw43t5WiGGmS2bTxVViA2yshyEpkoT&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22filesystemhub%22%7D%5D&X-ARR-LOG-ID=2b8d3d22-7bdd-4bfb-b190-b5e21dff8aab 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 558 1979 15
2016-10-18 07:45:15 ~1ZUPBOT POST /api/filesystemhub/send transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=GCS79RrlnHMnFmIPrMvLpheeo4m1Gd%2FudwM7ob%2FTegTtyL21OW0hnz0yBGV94sTHK9iwgN%2BQOCxxgcwAIc5LzPNg1qeS65bjIVFw43t5WiGGmS2bTxVViA2yshyEpkoT&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22filesystemhub%22%7D%5D&X-ARR-LOG-ID=e9e4a5ba-d60c-4c31-b86a-efa9b238ba6b 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 558 1963 0
2016-10-18T07:47:16  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2016-10-18 07:46:55 ~1ZUPBOT GET / - 80 - 100.76.188.54 AlwaysOn - - zupbot.azurewebsites.net 200 0 64 0 439 15
2016-10-18 07:46:55 ZUPBOT GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=33e6424d-a443-485d-bd80-63c4a9423950 80 - 191.233.85.165 AlwaysOn ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 - zupbot.azurewebsites.net 301 0 0 622 616 15
2016-10-18 07:47:48 ~1ZUPBOT POST /api/filesystemhub/send transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=GCS79RrlnHMnFmIPrMvLpheeo4m1Gd%2FudwM7ob%2FTegTtyL21OW0hnz0yBGV94sTHK9iwgN%2BQOCxxgcwAIc5LzPNg1qeS65bjIVFw43t5WiGGmS2bTxVViA2yshyEpkoT&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22filesystemhub%22%7D%5D&X-ARR-LOG-ID=8f3866f6-f878-4bca-bcab-bf171b0a0f76 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 558 1993 38
2016-10-18 07:47:48 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/vfs/LogFiles/ X-ARR-LOG-ID=dcb95419-ba9a-4230-a67d-6a198d1fedb9 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 1435 1189 42
2016-10-18 07:47:48 ~1ZUPBOT POST /api/commandstream/send transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&shell=CMD&connectionToken=G%2BH2XNxiB1nlUwedD%2FJVPlw0aEpOXmen5n38IrNMt6rxwapqhtEp1%2BoMqTzbXK3GNlGhPhqzf7cWdO5XQbi%2BNN1UIAkq4g8X0q7x9FG%2B2wo9fMlSQxlONoiqaw45sKQM&X-ARR-LOG-ID=efe496a1-eb65-4734-bb98-8c089d250fe2 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 454 1810 46
2016-10-18 07:47:48 ~1ZUPBOT POST /api/filesystemhub/send transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=GCS79RrlnHMnFmIPrMvLpheeo4m1Gd%2FudwM7ob%2FTegTtyL21OW0hnz0yBGV94sTHK9iwgN%2BQOCxxgcwAIc5LzPNg1qeS65bjIVFw43t5WiGGmS2bTxVViA2yshyEpkoT&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22filesystemhub%22%7D%5D&X-ARR-LOG-ID=c76729f3-1fd9-4270-8248-be64bfc6344b 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 558 1993 15
2016-10-18 07:47:48 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/vfs/LogFiles/ X-ARR-LOG-ID=4bf1a755-1940-4926-a24e-97035609ee13 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 1435 1189 15
2016-10-18 07:47:48 ~1ZUPBOT POST /api/commandstream/send transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&shell=CMD&connectionToken=G%2BH2XNxiB1nlUwedD%2FJVPlw0aEpOXmen5n38IrNMt6rxwapqhtEp1%2BoMqTzbXK3GNlGhPhqzf7cWdO5XQbi%2BNN1UIAkq4g8X0q7x9FG%2B2wo9fMlSQxlONoiqaw45sKQM&X-ARR-LOG-ID=f42a27e4-f37d-4b9c-ae61-2e4b5215afad 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 454 1810 78
2016-10-18 07:47:49 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/vfs/LogFiles/DetailedErrors/ X-ARR-LOG-ID=ce2b303f-07fc-49f9-8115-e328e6e76f77 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 921 1219 371
2016-10-18 07:47:49 ~1ZUPBOT POST /api/commandstream/send transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&shell=CMD&connectionToken=G%2BH2XNxiB1nlUwedD%2FJVPlw0aEpOXmen5n38IrNMt6rxwapqhtEp1%2BoMqTzbXK3GNlGhPhqzf7cWdO5XQbi%2BNN1UIAkq4g8X0q7x9FG%2B2wo9fMlSQxlONoiqaw45sKQM&X-ARR-LOG-ID=2dd699b4-bd6b-4e1d-a9cd-de2ca8000b63 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 454 1827 251
2016-10-18 07:47:49 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/vfs/LogFiles/DetailedErrors/ X-ARR-LOG-ID=db6c6516-8ea0-41c4-9f59-00eac957b7d0 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 921 1219 420
2016-10-18 07:47:51 ~1ZUPBOT POST /api/filesystemhub/send transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=GCS79RrlnHMnFmIPrMvLpheeo4m1Gd%2FudwM7ob%2FTegTtyL21OW0hnz0yBGV94sTHK9iwgN%2BQOCxxgcwAIc5LzPNg1qeS65bjIVFw43t5WiGGmS2bTxVViA2yshyEpkoT&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22filesystemhub%22%7D%5D&X-ARR-LOG-ID=d289cec5-c906-4c09-b9f8-07797cff2859 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 558 2013 1173
2016-10-18 07:47:51 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/vfs/LogFiles/DetailedErrors/ErrorPage000001.htm X-ARR-LOG-ID=782d0672-eb8f-48d5-b313-99581ae03e60 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 2939 1324 31
2016-10-18 07:47:58 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/vfs/LogFiles/DetailedErrors/ErrorPage000001.htm X-ARR-LOG-ID=3f1206bd-ac0c-4774-bc22-792b36509b77 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 304 0 0 573 1362 31
2016-10-18 07:48:15 ~1ZUPBOT POST /api/filesystemhub/send transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=GCS79RrlnHMnFmIPrMvLpheeo4m1Gd%2FudwM7ob%2FTegTtyL21OW0hnz0yBGV94sTHK9iwgN%2BQOCxxgcwAIc5LzPNg1qeS65bjIVFw43t5WiGGmS2bTxVViA2yshyEpkoT&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22filesystemhub%22%7D%5D&X-ARR-LOG-ID=173d55b3-2af1-452a-9e7d-035ab003a871 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 558 1993 31
2016-10-18 07:48:15 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/vfs/LogFiles/ X-ARR-LOG-ID=a8089ad4-77a7-4a38-9b8f-60a7382e9078 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 1435 1189 46
2016-10-18 07:48:15 ~1ZUPBOT POST /api/commandstream/send transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&shell=CMD&connectionToken=G%2BH2XNxiB1nlUwedD%2FJVPlw0aEpOXmen5n38IrNMt6rxwapqhtEp1%2BoMqTzbXK3GNlGhPhqzf7cWdO5XQbi%2BNN1UIAkq4g8X0q7x9FG%2B2wo9fMlSQxlONoiqaw45sKQM&X-ARR-LOG-ID=d85a6f06-dab8-4e00-8783-fc2b2b35bad2 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 454 1810 78
2016-10-18 07:48:15 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/vfs/LogFiles/Application/ X-ARR-LOG-ID=c22eb57a-9182-4f28-a8e2-6eb79c9229df 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 955 1213 46
2016-10-18 07:48:15 ~1ZUPBOT POST /api/filesystemhub/send transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=GCS79RrlnHMnFmIPrMvLpheeo4m1Gd%2FudwM7ob%2FTegTtyL21OW0hnz0yBGV94sTHK9iwgN%2BQOCxxgcwAIc5LzPNg1qeS65bjIVFw43t5WiGGmS2bTxVViA2yshyEpkoT&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22filesystemhub%22%7D%5D&X-ARR-LOG-ID=dca0d0e9-aa13-48a5-a3e2-2301e489a170 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 558 2010 15
2016-10-18 07:48:15 ~1ZUPBOT POST /api/commandstream/send transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.4&shell=CMD&connectionToken=G%2BH2XNxiB1nlUwedD%2FJVPlw0aEpOXmen5n38IrNMt6rxwapqhtEp1%2BoMqTzbXK3GNlGhPhqzf7cWdO5XQbi%2BNN1UIAkq4g8X0q7x9FG%2B2wo9fMlSQxlONoiqaw45sKQM&X-ARR-LOG-ID=8d87055b-416c-4436-8eb6-3c50decac7a9 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 454 1824 31
2016-10-18 07:48:15 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/vfs/LogFiles/Application/ X-ARR-LOG-ID=83fddf57-3bec-41c6-bbb4-1da9eeef402a 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 955 1213 93
2016-10-18 07:48:18 ~1ZUPBOT GET /api/vfs/LogFiles/Application/92c9b0-17136-stdout-1476773093416.txt X-ARR-LOG-ID=393dda53-d22f-41dc-ad80-0c92426e301c 443 - 58.146.120.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/53.0.2785.143+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=92c9b036f6d8a29ccfa03c2d92c7662a09d249bdd24ba672d7f285f0899fc7b6 https://zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 872 1307 15
```

I further recorded this erorr inside my azure.err file

```
2016-10-18T07:27:11.642Z:
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
  <<< async stack >>>
  at doLogStream (C:\Users\vivz\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.7.0\node_modules\azure-cli\lib\commands\asm\site.log.js:259:20)
  at __2 (C:\Users\vivz\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.7.0\node_modules\azure-cli\lib\commands\asm\site.log.js:96:19)
  <<< raw stack >>>
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:564:26)
  stack: [Getter/Setter],
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  __frame: 
   { name: 'doLogStream',
     line: 251,
     file: 'C:\\Users\\vivz\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v6.7.0\\node_modules\\azure-cli\\lib\\commands\\asm\\site.log.js',
     prev: 
      { name: '__2',
        line: 82,
        file: 'C:\\Users\\vivz\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v6.7.0\\node_modules\\azure-cli\\lib\\commands\\asm\\site.log.js',
        prev: undefined,
        calls: 2,
        active: false,
        offset: 14,
        col: 18 },
     calls: 0,
     active: false,
     offset: 8,
     col: 19 },
  rawStack: [Getter] }
Error: read ECONNRESET
  <<< async stack >>>
  at doLogStream (C:\Users\vivz\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.7.0\node_modules\azure-cli\lib\commands\asm\site.log.js:259:20)
  at __2 (C:\Users\vivz\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.7.0\node_modules\azure-cli\lib\commands\asm\site.log.js:96:19)
  <<< raw stack >>>
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:564:26)
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I think it's not quite clear what you expect to see. What makes you think your service is restarting every 4 mins?

Comment: if you dont mind telling, what are those 304 get errors that keep popping up and any ideas what may be wrong with the azure.err file

Comment: [HTTP 304](https://httpstatuses.com/304) should only be an info and `ECONNRESET` sounds like the connection being reset by the client.

Comment: @PirateApp Have you read up on HTTP 304? It's not a site-reload error. Simple web search yields many resources, including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603595/why-am-i-getting-304-not-modified-error-on-some-links-when-using-httpwebrequ).

Comment: @DavidMakogon yes I have researched the 304 but what are these events with the 'X-ARR-ID' how can I get rid of those from the log stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the "Always On" setting, what you are seeing are the keep alive pings App Service does to keep your site "hot" when this feature is enabled.

[image]

Comment: but that would mean that the site wont be ready to accept requests when someone pings in the middle of the night wont it, i believe it stays on for sometime and then powers down till i receives a request making it take a while to serve that request

Comment: @PirateApp My comment was about helping you get rid of the 'X-ARR-ID' lines in your log. There seems to be 3 or 4 different questions in your post. 

a) is my site getting restarted every 4 minutes?

b) What are the x-arr-id lines I see in the logs?

c) What is the 304 Error?

d) What is the ECONRESET error in Azure.err file?

I'll try to answer them below:

Comment: a) there is no evidence your site is being restarted every 4 minutes, what you are seeing every 4 minutes is the "Always On" ping.

b) the "x-arr-id" lines in the log are the evidence of the "Always On" ping

c) HTTP 304 is not an error but rather an indication that the result for the request being made has not changed and can be served form cache. In other words it's telling the client to not bother download anything, just serve it from the client cache

d)For the ECONRESET I'm not 100% certain but it's usually a result of client terminating connection rather than server going down.

Answer (score 1):

The first lines, until the "GET /DebugConsole [...] zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net", are legit requests - the requests are made to the zupbot.azurewebsites.net address.
The requests "GET /DebugConsole [...] zupbot.scm.azurewebsites.net" are made from the debugging console and are made to the SCM (the service through which you publish the app from Visual Studio).
304 means that the info from the file you requested has not modified - see https://httpstatuses.com/304 .
X-ARR-LOG-ID is the of ARR (Application Request Routing) Affinity for each user - for details see here: [[https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/16/disable-session-affinity-cookie-arr-cookie-for-azure-web-apps/]](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/16/disable-session-affinity-cookie-arr-cookie-for-azure-web-apps/)

I see no message that your webapp is restarting, so the errors are not from the web server.