# Routing issue in single page application

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have developed web app using angularjs single page application.Now I am building my own web server using nodejs.

The index page is visible when page is loaded but on navigation to other pages.
The get request goes on infinite loop with 304 status.

**Please note I need  css and javascript for bootstrap and jquery.**When these are loaded I receive the error.I have inserted app.js(server config),index.js(nodejs routing config),moduleapp.js(angularjs routing config) and picture of error.
[image]

```js
   

 var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
       
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl : "/views/home.hbs",
            controller : "homeCtrl"
        })

        .when("/aboutme",{
            templateUrl:"/views/aboutme.hbs",
            controller:"aboutCtrl"
        })

        .when("/education", {
            templateUrl : "/views/education.hbs",
            controller : "eduCtrl"
        })

        .when("/interest",{
            templateUrl:"/views/interest.hbs",
            controller:"interestCtrl"
        })

        .when("/gallery",{
            templateUrl:"/views/gallery.hbs",
            controller:"galleryCtrl"
        })
        
        .when("/contact", {
            templateUrl : "/views/contact.hbs",
            controller : "contactCtrl"
        });

    });


    app.controller("homeCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.msg = "Welcome to homepage";
    });

    app.controller("aboutCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.msg = "About me";
    });


    app.controller("eduCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.msg = "Hi Academics";
    });

    app.controller("interestCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.msg = "My interests";
    });

    app.controller("galleryCtrl",function($scope){
        $scope.msg="My photos";
    })
    app.controller("contactCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.msg = "Contact me";
    });
```

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('layout');
    });

    router.get('/:name', function(req, res, next) {
        var name=req.params.name;
      res.render(name);
    });

    module.exports = router;

<!-- end snippet -->





    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    var hbs=require('express-handlebars');

    var index = require('./routes/index');


    var app = express();

    // view engine setup

    app.engine('hbs',hbs({extname:'hbs'}))
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use('/', index);
    app.use('*', index);

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });

    // error handler
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      // set locals, only providing error in development
      res.locals.message = err.message;
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

      // render the error page
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error');
    });

    module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Check this out! https://stackoverflow.com/a/2603644/2079271

Comment: Thank you but the partials as defined by ngroute is not rendered.I tried changing app.js and ng-route but its not working! I agree 304 is not an error.