# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, vue.js, lottie

I've been looking for how to solve this error but i didn't understand very well how t fix it.

I'm working with lottie-web on a project and i have to set the params of the animation on an object to pass it as a parameter later.

My component:

```
import Lottie from './../../node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie';

export default {
  name: 'Illustration',
  mounted() {
    this.animationParams = {
      container: document.getElementById('animation'),
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: 'true',
      autoplay: 'false',
      path: '/src/data/animation.json',
    };
    Lottie.loadAnimation(this.animationParams);
  },
  data() {
    return {
      animationParams: {
      },
    };
  },
```

but when this line is executed:

```
    Lottie.loadAnimation(this.animationParams);
```

i get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange
```

what i have seen on other answers here in Stackoverflow is that i don't have to parse the json since it's already parsed, but i don't know how to NOT parse it.

here's what's inside the json file: http://myjson.com/s0kn6.

how do i have to load that json file without parsing it?

Comment: Take a look at the network tab of your browsers devtools. You probably don't get a json but instead html.

Comment: well, i checked it, and that's not the case :/

Comment: @CarlosPisarello It's possible that the specified path (`/src/data/animation.json`) is not found on your server, which might be setup to redirect to a 404 page (i.e., HTML), which fails to parse as JSON. I would double-check the corresponding network response for that path in DevTools.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a screenshot of your network call from chrome developer tools and also the response for that network call?  What @tony19 has commented makes sense at this point.

Comment: Sure! @highhope

here it is:

https://ibb.co/drGVM7

the file is Cuentas.json (on the post i changed it to animation.json to better understanding of the problem)

Comment: Show the response also please.

Comment: ooooh, there we go :  https://ibb.co/iJF1Tn

Comment: now i get it, i just don't understand what's going on now.

Comment: that's obviously not the data inside the JSON file i'm calling

Comment: Yup so @tony19 was correct.   And see if this post helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603595/why-am-i-getting-304-not-modified-error-on-some-links-when-using-httpwebrequ

Comment: I could finally get the json Data, i was looking on another projects structures and what i did was move the data folder to the /static/ path and have it no longer on the /src/ path.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely your server is serving `/src/data/animation.json`. Instead of using `path` use `animationData` and just set the animation object directly (instead of via a server call).

First, I would just set the animation data to a regular ES6 module that exports an object instead of json.

**/src/data/animation.js**

```
export default {
  // your animation data
}
```

Note that it's a javascript file, not a json file. Then in your component, just import the object.

```
import Lottie from './../../node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie';
import animationData from "/src/data/animation"

export default {
  name: 'Illustration',
  mounted() {
    this.animationParams = {
      container: document.getElementById('animation'),
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: 'true',
      autoplay: 'false',
      animationData,
    };
    Lottie.loadAnimation(this.animationParams);
  },
  data() {
    return {
      animationParams: {
      },
    };
  },
```

This is documented [here](http://airbnb.io/lottie/web/getting-started.html#html).

This will make your initial bundle larger, but you won't have to make an additional call to the server for the animation data.

Barring that, you will need to move `animation.json` to some path that is being served by your server and set `path` to a url relative to the page that is currently loaded.