# Fetch API Returning 304 Not Modified in Angular

Tags: angular, caching, fetch-api, http-status-code-304

I created an Angular frontend and a .Net backend, API call from my Angular client that was initially working has stopped working. The only change I made was change the structure of the  object sent to frontend. I have cleared my cache, still issue persist.

```
fetch(URL) 
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

    console.log(data)

})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "(304) Not Modified" error on some links when using HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603595/why-am-i-getting-304-not-modified-error-on-some-links-when-using-httpwebrequ). It is just a notification to the client that the resource has not been changed. Usually web servers do this automatically.

Comment: @DucHo But in this case, the resource data has changed but I still get the 304.

Comment: Does the fetch command work on any other website or browser? If so then I think the problem may come from the .NET server.