# What is the main purpose of WebExceptionStatus.Success?

Tags: system.net.webexception

I am a bit confused about the purpose of the enum value Success of the WebExceptionStatus enumeration. I did a search and did not find this enumeration being used outside the WebException class. This is very confusing to me. Why would an exception be used to indicate a successful action/state. Am I missing something, or did I not search thouroughly enough? Was it introduced for future functionality?

Please if anyone does know its basic purpose I would be thankfull if s/he shares with us the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366848/httpwebrequest-getresponse-throws-webexception-on-http-304) might help.

Comment: You mean when I send a request, and that request is recieved successfuly on the server, but the server needs some more information, so it throws a WebException with Status == Success, and HTTP Status Code in the range 300-399?

Comment: @csharpenter Yes, something along those lines.